# what are the values in haarcascade frontalface .xml

Tags: opencv

in opencv frontalface cascade .xml file what are tree node threshold and left value 
such as

```
    3 7 14 4 -1.  rect
    3 9 14 2 2.    rect 
    4.0141958743333817e-003  threshold 
    0.0337941907346249    left value

    0.8378106951713562    right value
```

If u know what these values are represent plese give me solution

i assume following please correct me if i am wrong

1) there are 21 stage each stage contain weak classifier

2)3 7 14 -1 represent the rectangle where 3 and 7 (are corodinates of pixel that we need to sum for bright area )14 width and 4 height of image amd multiple that sumt with -1 (weight)

3)3 9 14 2 2 2 is a rect similar to above for dark area and calculate sum and multiple it with weight

4) now make the substraction from values in step (2) and (3) if sutraction < threshold then add left value else add right value 
si=milarly for all feature in that stage now add all values from all feature if it is less than stage thershold then go for next stage else reject that area for detection

(5)up to how much stage i need to pass to confirm that it is a face is all

4.0141958743333817e-003  threshold what is reperesnt either the complete exponential value

or  threshold range in between 4.0141958743333817e  3
please correct me if i am wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Its probably the values of activation function of the trained neural network.